# How does CorFlags.exe /32BIT+ work?

Tags: clr, loader, corflags

I guess my question is about the [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) Loader. I want to understand the mechanics behind [CorFlags.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) `/32BIT+` functionality.

We know that when one starts an assembly compiled with the *Any CPU* flag set on 64-bit Windows, it starts as a 64-bit process. If one run `CorFlags /32BIT+` on that assembly, it will start as a 32-bit process. I think this is a fascinating feature.

I have so many questions about it:

1. How is it implemented?
2. Does the OS Loader get involved?
3. Is possible to build a custom application (I guess an unmanaged one) that loads 32-bit or 64-bit CLR at a wish?

Is there an article, book, blog, etc that explains the inner workings of this feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't well documented in any place I know of, I can only point you to a relevant MSDN article.  Yes, your assumption is correct, the loader in Windows XP and up has awareness of managed executables.  It automatically loads the .NET loader shim (c:\windows\system32\mscoree.dll), the relevant entrypoint is [_CorValidateImage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ce9k7xb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  The Remarks section in the linked MSDN article describes the mechanism that turns a 32-bit .exe file into a 64-bit process:

> In Windows XP and later versions, the operating system loader checks for managed modules by examining the COM Descriptor Directory bit in the common object file format (COFF) header. A set bit indicates a managed module. If the loader detects a managed module, it loads MsCorEE.dll and calls _CorValidateImage, which performs the following actions:
>
> - Confirms that the image is a valid managed module.
> - Changes the entry point in the image to an entry point in the common language runtime (CLR).
> - For 64-bit versions of Windows, modifies the image that is in memory by transforming it from PE32 to PE32+ format.
> - Returns to the loader when the managed module images are loaded.
>
> For executable images, the operating system loader then calls the
>   _CorExeMain function, regardless of the entry point specified in the executable. For DLL assembly images, the loader calls the _CorDllMain
>   function.
>
> _CorExeMain or _CorDllMain performs the following actions:
>
> - Initializes the CLR.
> - Locates the managed entry point from the assembly's CLR header.
> - Begins execution.
>
> The loader calls the _CorImageUnloading function when managed module
>   images are unloaded. However, this function does not perform any
>   action; it just returns.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This is a good starting point. I wanted to find out how clr deals with .reloc sections. I dug in sscli, mostly in pedecoder.h/pewriter.cpp and found my answers. Still there are many questions (e.g. what about Windows 2000 x64) but I guess I will find the answers in sscli.

Comment: That's an easy one, Windows 2000 x64 has last been seen used by the great white Yeti.

Comment: Wow. I wonder if there is any way to take advantage of this "special awareness" to create proper fat (native code) binaries for Windows.

Comment: Tried that, found no answer. Probably, this magic won't work at all if no .NET is installed in the OS. Which renders this useless for native executables.

Answer (score 2):

To add on Hans' answer, there is also some Windows kernel mode code that responds to that flag. Every loaded executable has a kernel structure, `SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION`, associated with it. Here's its symbol information:

```
 0: kd> dt nt!_SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION
           +0x000 TransferAddress           : Ptr64 Void
           +0x008 ZeroBits                  : Uint4B
           +0x010 MaximumStackSize          : Uint8B
           +0x018 CommittedStackSize        : Uint8B
           +0x020 SubSystemType             : Uint4B
           +0x024 SubSystemMinorVersion     : Uint2B
           +0x026 SubSystemMajorVersion     : Uint2B
           +0x024 SubSystemVersion          : Uint4B
           +0x028 GpValue                   : Uint4B
           +0x02c ImageCharacteristics      : Uint2B
           +0x02e DllCharacteristics        : Uint2B
           +0x030 Machine                   : Uint2B
           +0x032 ImageContainsCode         : UChar
           +0x033 ImageFlags                : UChar
           +0x033 ComPlusNativeReady        : Pos 0, 1 Bit
           +0x033 ComPlusILOnly             : Pos 1, 1 Bit
           +0x033 ImageDynamicallyRelocated : Pos 2, 1 Bit
           +0x033 ImageMappedFlat           : Pos 3, 1 Bit
           +0x033 BaseBelow4gb              : Pos 4, 1 Bit
           +0x033 Reserved                  : Pos 5, 3 Bits
```

The flags `ComPlusILOnly` and `ComPlusNativeReady` are related to .NET, `ComPlusILOnly` simply tells if the assembly is [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) only (not mixed or native - in which case the assembly is already architecture specific), and `ComPlusNativeReady` is 1 only if /32BIT+ is not set ([32BITREQ or 32BITPREF in newer CorFlags version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Those flags are checked during `nt!PspAllocateProcess` and based on them a `32-bit` or `64-bit` process is created.

[I wrote about it](http://debugandconquer.blogspot.co.il/2015/04/the-relationship-between-net-and.html) with some details.

Comment: Many thanks!!! I've got confused in calculating some offsets of fields this structure using obsoleted information in Windows NT/2000 Native API Reference.