# CorFlags says my .NET-Program runs as 64bit while DumpBin means it is 32bit

Tags: .net, 32bit-64bit

I created a project and compiled it as `Any CPU`. on x64-Windows. As I have trouble to reference that assembly from my code I checked the runtime and the target-plattform:

[image: x64vsx86]

As you can see the target plattform is x64 when running on an x64-OS (as mine). I checked `DumpBin` also:

```
PE signature found

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               3 number of sections
        57A49000 time date stamp Fri Aug 05 15:09:20 2016
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              E0 size of optional header
             102 characteristics
                   Executable
                   32 bit word machine
```

However when I run `CorFlags` it´s giving me x64 as plattform for that assembly:

```
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 9
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 0
Signed    : 1
```

As far as I understand when I chose `Any CPU` as target platform the OS will chose how to execute the assembly. On an 64bit system it´ll run in 64bit, on 32bit-OS as 32bit respectivly.

So my question is: what version am I *actually* targetting? 32 or 64bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's entirely normal.  AnyCPU means that it can run on any cpu so the *machine* field in the header cannot be relevant.  Having to pick *something*, it just picks x86.  Keeps it compatible with ancient Windows versions like Win98 and Win2k.

The [special heroics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389756/how-does-corflags-exe-32bit-work/10392396#10392396) happen on a 64-bit operating system, the OS loader needs help to creating a 64-bit process from a 32-bit executable, that requires patching internal loader structures.  The mscoree.dll "loader-shim" gets that job done as described in the linked post.

So you do *not* target any particular version.  It truly is AnyCPU.

Comment: So I´d better be off relying on `corflags`, don´t I?

Comment: Maybe you are better off relying on the project settings.  I can't tell why you are asking this question.